# Low framerate in MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm writing a 2D puzzle game in MonoGame. I just added my first moving sprite to the program, and discovered that I'm getting about 10fps on it, and I haven't got the faintest idea why. I don't know if I can provide enough information to get help here, but I thought it was worth a shot. For reference, the moving object is a Ball.

Main update routine:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        Exit();

    MouseState newState = Mouse.GetState();

    if (newState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && oldState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
    {
        MouseLeftClicked(newState.X, newState.Y);
    }

    oldState = newState;

    if (gameState == GameState.Playing)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Ball ball in ballList)
            {
                ball.Update(gameTime);
            }
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException)
        {
        }
    }
    // TODO: Add your update logic here

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Ball update routine:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    this.pos += this.motion * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
}
```

Main Draw routine:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    // TODO: Add your drawing code here
    spriteBatch.Begin();

    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
        {
            if (gameGrid[x, y] != null)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundTile, gameGrid[x, y].rect, Color.White);
            }
        }
    }


    //Draw menu
    if (gameState == GameState.StartMenu)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(startButton, orbPosition, Color.White);
    }

    //Draw game while playing
    if (gameState == GameState.Playing)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
            {
                try
                {
                    gameGrid[x, y].pipe.Draw(spriteBatch);
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (Wheel wheel in wheelList)
        {
            wheel.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        foreach (Ball ball in ballList)
        {
            ball.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }

    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Ball Draw routine:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    int sprite = (int)color;

    Rectangle sourceRect = new Rectangle(sprite * spriteSize, 0, spriteSize, spriteSize);
    Rectangle ballRect = new Rectangle((int)this.pos.X, (int)this.pos.Y, spriteSize * scale, spriteSize * scale);

    //spriteBatch.Begin();

    spriteBatch.Draw(this.texture, ballRect, sourceRect, Color.White);

    //spriteBatch.End();
}
```

Comment: Did you try running a profiler and seeing where the bottle neck is? By default I believe the fps is 60.

Comment: I've not heard of a profiler before - what is it and how do I run it?

Comment: Profilers perform program analysis such as how much space a program takes up, how long function calls takes, etc.. Simple google search will return numerous amounts of profilers that are available out there and most plug in with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code and it does not lag when providing a texture. I had to make slight modification to your code in order to make it work since you omitted parts from it. I suppose the omitted parts may be responsible but it is unlikely. I don't know on what kind of machine you are testing this but, I will provide some recommendations in order to resolve the problem you have locally.

When writing performant code, forget everything you know about 'object oriented behaviour' and think data. Data oriented design is all about sticking data that belongs together into big chunks and processing it all at once. This is much faster. In many cases as for game design, when there is one, there are many. Use that to your advantage and pass the whole array and act upon it directly on the spot.

Avoid nesting exceptions and iterative loops if possible. Exceptions are expensive when they occur, they should only be used when it is very *exceptional*, or if it is *extremely unusual* that the case actually does occur, and you wish to handle this 'edge' case by throwing an exception to force consumers of the code to handle it.

```
 for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
        {
            try
            {
                gameGrid[x, y].pipe.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Catching the Null Reference Exception that you nested in the two for loops might be a bad idea. If you need to throw from one of these, and that allows you to draw the next consider why the throw is necessary if you wish to keep the code as it is. If it's there to catch empties in gameGrid or pipe, consider that a constructor should always put the item in a valid state and that the list should always be 'complete'. If an element stops existing it should not be in the list anymore. Otherwise, if one failure means all fail move the try block outside. This is more common.

Profiling your application is a mechanism that helps you find where things are slower than you expected and sometimes even *why*. Here's a reference on how to do this in visual studio. [Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) as well as [Walkthrough: Profiling Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182398.aspx).

That said, none of these would slow your application down to the sort of degree you are describing. Therefore I advice you to edit your question and include other relevant sections of the code that may be the cause. I have attached below a sample constructed from your small example with some small modifications in order to simulate your environment in a much more extreme manner. This example draws 100 rectangles of which each one is 50x50 and they all rescale and move like your application does as well. These are 100 tiles, if this is slow for you on its own you should definitely look into the profiler topic above if you are using visual studio or try getting the latest binaries from [Mono Game's official website](http://www.monogame.net/) or your latest graphics card drivers.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    public IList<Ball> Balls { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        var rand = new Random();
        Balls = new List<Ball>(5);
        for(var iii = 0; iii < 100; ++iii)
            Balls.Add(new Ball(GraphicsDevice, new Vector2(rand.Next(50, 500), rand.Next(50, 500))));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        foreach (var ball in Balls)
            ball.Update(gameTime);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        foreach (var ball in Balls)
            ball.Draw(spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}

public class Ball
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; private set; }
    public double Scale { get; private set; }

    public Ball(GraphicsDevice gd, Vector2 initialPosition)
    {
        Texture = new Texture2D(gd, 50, 50);
        Position = initialPosition;
        var data = new Color[100*100];
        for (var iii = 0; iii < data.Length; ++iii) data[iii] = Color.YellowGreen;
        Texture.SetData(data);
    }

    private bool _increaseScale, _increaseX, _increaseY;

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (Scale < 1)
            _increaseScale = true;
        else if (Scale > 4)
            _increaseScale = false;

        if (Position.X < 50)
            _increaseX = true;
        else if (Position.X > 500)
            _increaseX = false;

        if (Position.Y < 50)
            _increaseY = true;
        else if (Position.Y > 500)
            _increaseY = false;

        Scale += (_increaseScale ? 1.5 : -1.5) * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        Position += new Vector2((float)((_increaseX ? 100 : -100)*gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds), (float)((_increaseY ? 100 : -100)*gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds));
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        var source = new Rectangle(0, 0, Texture.Height, Texture.Width);
        var dest = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Texture.Width * (int)Scale, Texture.Height* (int)Scale);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, dest, source, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Comment: The game grid is an 8x6 array of tiles that makes up the main play screen. Each tile can have a Pipe object associated or not. The `try...catch` is to iterate through the tiles, draw the associated pipe if it's there, and not crash if that tile doesn't have one. I didn't realise that was computationally expensive; I'll try replacing that with a proper list of Pipes, see if that fixes it. If not, I'll try the Profiler thing.

I'm also using bog standard arrays rather than the IList thing you used in your example program - what's the difference there?

Comment: IList<T> is an interface that allows you to send in ArrayLists and more. I use it to give consumers of my code the freedom to implement their own list and handle it differently. One application I saw a user take was to write a "SelfRemoveList", where an item that determines its own state can expire itself from the list without knowing its inside a list. Other than implementing yourself, there's more than List<T> they may pass, so there's that. If I know I require a List<T> for some reason, I define it as such.

Comment: Removing the `try..catch` in favour of a proper array of pipes solved the problem straight away. Thanks!